# on reloading/refreshing the page the dojo/ready function is not called

Tags: dojo

When refreshing/reloading a page, the dojo/ready function is not called, so the page is not loaded properly.  Sometimes it is working properly; some times not.

```
window.onload = function() {
 setTimeout(function(){document.body.style.opacity="100";},100);
 require(["dojo/ready"], function(ready){ 
     ready(function(){
            alert("ready");
     });
});
```

};

This is my window onload code.  Sometimes I am getting the alert ready, sometimes not.  I cannot figure out the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Were you able to try my solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to not use `window.onload`.

Instead, include your script as a js file like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/appRoot/js/my.js"></script>
```

Then in your my.js file:

```
require([ "dojo", "dojo/domReady!" ], function(dojo) {
    // Code in here will be run only when the page is ready.
});
```

I am using this with dojo 1.7, but this is valid through 1.9.

See also the [dojo/domReady! documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/domReady.html).